# Static counter that increments for every line printed in output?

Tags: java, recursion, counter

I have a long output, and I am trying to number the lines printed in the output to make sure all of them are printing correctly. I would just use a regular counter in my method, but I am using recursion to print everything, so it has been hard to get an accurate count of the number of lines being printed. How could I make some sort of static counter that prints before each line is printed to essentially number each line?

Comment: Where are you having trouble?  (1) Define `int lines` as a class member variable. (2) `lines++` after every line printed.   By the way, it only needs to be (and only should be) static if your printing function is static.

Comment: Pass the line value into the recursive method and return it as the result (applying back to the local variable).  Alternatively, if the method is returning some other value (like a exit value), you could encapsulate the line count into a POJO and pass that through instead

Comment: Or redirect the results to a file and run wc -l on the file to count the lines. Or open the results file in vi with line numbers on.

Comment: Ah, I see what I was doing now, I had two recursive calls and I guess I just kept putting the print statement in the wrong spot. Thank you! I thought I was going to have to make some sort of counting method but this is much simpler.

Comment: Please don't edit the title to make it seem like the question is closed.  A question is closed when the community or a moderator determines that the question does not follow our site guidelines.  If you indicate that a question is closed when it is not, you bypass our moderation system.  If an answer solved your issue, please consider clicking the green check mark to accept it.  Accepting an answer is separate from being closed or open.

Comment: Oh alright thank you! I thought that closed meant the question was answered, thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create something like `CounterHolder` and increment it every time you are trying to get value:

```
public class CounterHolder{

    private static int counter = 0;

    private CounterHolder(){}

    public static int getCounter(){
        return counter++;
    }

}
```

**UPD:**

You can also add custom printing method here:

```
public class CounterHolder{

    private static int counter = 0;

    private CounterHolder(){}

    public static void print(String msg){
        System.out.println(String.format("%d -> %s", counter++, msg));
    }

}
```